# How to remove the date from a column containing both date and time using R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have read a csv  file

```
input <- read.csv("abc.csv",header=FALSE)
```

and the data frame looks like..

[image: look here]

i want my expected result like this..
in the timeStamp column i want to replace "**2017/03/10 08:35:07.996**" to only "**08:35:07.996**".

Tried a lot but could find any solution.Please help

Comment: I ran this code but received an Error:->Error in input$timeStamp : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors –

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Provide information as image only if they can't be posted as text (readable, searchable, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can set the `digits.secs` to 3, then convert the 'timeStamp' to DateTime class with `strptime` and `format` it

```
op <- options(digits.secs=3)
input$timeStamp <- format(strptime(input$timeStamp, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS"), "%H:%M:%OS")
```

---

Though, it is better not to use regex on timestamps, one way is to match one or more non-white space (`\\S+`) character followed by one or more white space (`\\s+`) from the start (`^`) of the string and replace it with blanks (`""`) so that the rest of the string i.e. time part remains

```
input$timeStamp <- sub("^\\S+\\s+", "", input$timeStamp)
```

Comment: I ran this code but received an Error:Error in input$timeStamp : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: @BibhuKalyandas  Please check the `str(input)`  This should work if it is a data.frame with column as 'timeStamp'.  May be you have a `matrix`..  Also, try i`nput[["timeStamp"]]` or `input[, "timeStamp"]`

Answer (score 1):

You can split the column into two using the separate function from the tidyr package...

```
newDat <- separate(Dat, timeStamp, into = c("date", "time"), sep = " ")
```

Then simply remove the date column if you don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

Use stringr library to deal with strings :

```
library(stringr) #Do install.packages("stringr") if you don' have it
input <- read.csv("abc.csv",header=FALSE)
input$timeStamp <- str_split(as.character(input$timeStamp)," ")[[1]][2]
```

Comment: I ran this above code but receives an Error: Error in stri_split_regex(string, pattern, n = n, simplify = simplify,  : 
  could not find function "as.charactet"

Comment: I'm guessing `as.charactet` should be `as.character`.